# C# XML Writer Format AmazonEnvelope for AU Scratchpad

Tags: c#, xml, string-formatting

OK so I'm trying to format this XML element so that it looks like this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "amzn-envelope.xsd");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Now this code outputs this XML element:

```
<AmazonEnvelope noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So it's almost there but the `xsi:` is missing before this `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`

I really don't know where I'm going wrong.

Also I have been in touch with amazon devs and they tell me that it must be formatted like I have asked. Though if you do some googling you will notice examples of the xml writer code which will output the following XML element:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
```

This is wrong, and gives an error in the scratch pad.

I hope my question makes sense.

thanks for the help.

Comment: When I get tired of fighting the Net Library I just use the simple method :             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement amazon = doc.CreateElement("AmazonEnvelope");
            amazon.InnerXml = "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"amzn-envelope.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"";
            doc.AppendChild(amazon);

Comment: @jdweng this doesn't work for my situation. I'm using `using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))`

Comment: Then use : string innerxml = "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"amzn-envelope.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"";
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("AmazonEnvelope");
                writer.WriteRaw(innerxml);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }