# WPF XAML merge default namespace definitions

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, namespaces

In a WPF application, you can create XmlnsDefinitions to map multiple namespaces from another assembly into one reference .

You can take advantage of that to map your own namespaces to the Microsoft default XmlnsDefinition, for example:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "MyLibrary.MyControls")]
```

This way, you don't even need to add a reference to your namespace in the XAML file, because they are already mapped to the default "xmlns".

So, if I had a control called "MyControl", I can use it like this (without any namespaces or prefixes):

```
<MyControl />
```

**My question is**: Can I merge the default Microsoft namespaces into a single one?

For example: I want to get rid of the "xmlns:x" namespace by merging it into "xmlns". I would have to reference all the namespaces in "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation".

Like this:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System...")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System...")]
...
```

So I can turn this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
```

Into this:

```
<Window Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    >
```

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427705/c-sharp-xml-writer-format-amazonenvelope-for-au-scratchpad#comment81843968_47427705.   string innerxml = "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"amzn-envelope.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\""; using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)) { writer.WriteStartElement("AmazonEnvelope"); writer.WriteRaw(innerxml); writer.WriteEndElement(); }

Comment: That question has nothing to do with mine.

Comment: I put my `UserControl` into `System.Windows.Controls`. And it does not work for me: `[assembly: System.Windows.Markup.XmlnsDefinition( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "System.Windows.Controls" )]` Looks like designer is seeing my class, but compiler not. Error: `The tag 'ContentViewer' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override existing namespace mappings as they are already present in the standard assembies, but you can try merging all .NET namespaces into your own XML namespace. Like this:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:foobar", "System.Windows.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:foobar", "System.Windows.Documents")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:foobar", "System.Windows.Shapes")]
// ...
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("urn:foobar", "FoobarLibrary.Controls")]
// ...
```

It *may* work (I haven't tried). Your XAML will look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="FoobarProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="urn:foobar"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Note that you can't get rid of `x` namespace:

1. It isn't mapped to .NET namespace, it's pure XML namespace and part of XAML language.
2. Doing so would cause conflicts (`x:Name` vs. `Name`).

Speaking of conflicts, merging namespaces like this is asking for trouble. You are likely to run into name conflicts which these namespaces are designed to solve.

Comment: The dumb net library always wants the default namespace as the last item.

Comment: "You can't override existing namespace mappings as they are already present in the standard assembies", I should have thought about that.